# Variational inference in PyStan API?

Tags: python, bayesian, stan

I can't find any mentioning of variational inference in [PyStan documentation](https://pystan.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html), even though it [has been added](http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.03431) in Stan itself. Am I missing something, or is the Python API just not implementing it yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not in PyStan 2.9.0, but we're working on integrating it.

Comment: It's available now, as of PyStan 2.14. http://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pystan.StanModel.vb

Answer (score 1):

Currently (PyStan 2.14), it's available under the [StanModel.vb()](http://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pystan.StanModel.vb) call.

```
>>> from pystan import StanModel
>>> m = StanModel(model_code='parameters {real y;} model {y ~ normal(0,1);}')
>>> results = m.vb()
>>> # results saved on disk in format inspired by CSV
>>> print(results['args']['sample_file'])
```