# Stan: how to use variational inference to fit a distribution

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, stan, probability-theory, pystan

Let‘s assume that I have a Poisson distribution with gamma=10. I would like to fit a Gaussian distribution, which minimizes KL divergence to the Poisson distribution.
This is possible with variational inference. How can I use Stan to do this optimization?

The [reference manual](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_21/reference-manual/vi-algorithms-chapter.html) has a chapter on VI but only provides some high level information on how it is implemented internally, not how to use it.

The [user guide](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_21/stan-users-guide-2_21.pdf) mentions VI in chapter 22.2 but only with some general remarks on its efficiency.

A related question here on SO might be: [Variational inference in PyStan API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35340732/variational-inference-in-pystan-api)

But that only asks whether advi has been implemented in PyStan (it has). There is no additional information.

Answer (score 1):

CmdStanPy contains an example notebook:

- https://cmdstanpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/variational_bayes.html
- https://github.com/stan-dev/cmdstanpy/blob/master/docs/notebooks/Variational%20Inference.ipynb

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for answering a question! However, please don't just answer with links, they can break or change so it would be difficult to accept your answer. Please see [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)